# MissForest R package error

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with missing values and I want to use missForest for the imputation of those missing values. However when I run the missForest function with the following call

```
 missForest(xmis = DataWithMarANDMNAR, maxiter = 100, ntree = 50,mtry = floor(sqrt(ncol(DataWithMarANDMNAR))), replace = TRUE, parallelize = c('no', 'variables', 'forests'))
```

I get the following error

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘predict’ for signature ‘"randomForest"’

I have randomForest package installed, as well as missForest obviously. What is the reason of this error and how can I handle it?

Answer (score 1):

OK the issue is that I was using two packages(stat and rrecsys) which shares same function name predict, and when there was a call to predict, the function was calling the predict from rrecsys rather than stat.